# Measure strip bending

Tags: bluetooth

I though of a bluetooth strip device, that would tell me the value of the angle and direction in 3D. I tried to search for one, but did not found anything. 
The only idea I've got so far is to set up a few gyroscopes in a straight line and constantly measure their position and thus calculate the bending value. Is there a device, that can do that?

Comment: check this out .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kc3foeu2-50

Comment: jsotola, sorry for my poor english. I meant the value of the angle and direction in 3D. Thanks for the video, that's very cool

Comment: there are bend sensors available but they do not work in 3D ..... http://www.flexpoint.com/product/bend-sensor/

Comment: how large would the device be?

Comment: about 1-3 feet long

Comment: could a camera be used to detect the position of the device?

Comment: jsotola, it was conceived as a single device, without any external devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you need to use strain gauges and build your own.

While bluetooth enabled strain gauges do exist, they are used as power meters for bicycles by measuring the amount of bend in the cranks. But the cranks only bend imperceptible amounts.

The other possible option would be a piezoelectric material on the surface of the piece, but again you'd have to build your own circuit to interpret the voltage change and calibrate it.

There isn't enough information about the setting to say if a accelerometer/gyroscope approach would work. We don't know if the entire artefact is fixed (e.g. bolted down) or can move without bending the strip.

Comment: The initial idea with gyroscopes definitely loses to suggested piezoelectric/strain gauges or optic ideas as it needs overwhelm calculations and may give wrong result if we will wave the stick. Strain gauges idea sounds more graceful. I'll dig deeper on this subject. Thank you!